# Guardar caracteres especiales en base de datos phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar en la base de datos por medio de un input de un formulario lo siguiente C:\Users\jcifuentes\Document's\ESTUDIOS, pero no me deja guardar y si le quito la comilla que tiene osea que quede C:\Users\jcifuentes\Documents\ESTUDIOS la guarda, pero uno revisa la base de datos y los backslash () se quitan solas y queda C:UsersjcifuentesDocumentsESTUDIOS ¿Como solucionaría ese error?

Comment: Qué tipo de dato tiene la Columba donde guardas eso?

Comment: El tipo de dato es Varchar

Comment: coloca tu código, qué lenguaje usas?, qué base de datos?. Te pregunto esas cosas porque por ejemplo si estas usando php el PDO te hace un saneamiento de cadenas antes de guardar la información en la base de datos. Saludos.

Comment: // Instrucción de agregar

   $ruta = $_POST['ruta'];

   $sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO mall (ruta) VALUES ('$ruta')";

   $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, 
                        $sentenciaSQL);
   echo json_encode($resultado);

Base de datos MySQL la de phpMyadmin